# "On the Subject of Cross Posting", a question by RJ

Tags: discussion

I've seen some people clearly state that a post has a cross post on another SE site (typically SO) and/or link each post to the other, but what are the community recommendations on this topic?

If I ask a question that may not be SharePoint specific, but relates to SharePoint development, should I:

- Ask on SO and tag it SharePoint
- Ask on SPSE
- Ask on both and cross reference the posts within each other

The reason I ask is I just posted a question on SO that is about Visual Studio, but relates to a SharePoint control. I asked myself, "Hmm, what if another SP developer has handled this in the past?" In order to get the best answer, I feel like cross posting would benefit the poster. However cross posting has downsides too, such as duplication of information (violating the SRP!), additional doling out of points, comment threads being segregated, etc.

Thoughts?

Comment: Good question, in fact I was thinking about it yesterday.

Comment: I will add that separating StackExchange communities from each other, when technology is very integrated with each other, puts this problem of cross-posting in play. I think there should be some integration with other StackExchange communities that are related. It's a system-wide change but it should be looked into for the sake of structure and searchability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean copying and pasting on another Stack site, please **don't**.  **Ever**. Seriously.

Here are the reasons given by the folks who know more about this than me:

> Allowing cross-posting is a slippery slope.
>
> If you might have slightly better odds of getting an answer by posting
> it on two sites, well, by gum, why not maximize your odds by posting
> it on twenty sites!
>
> There are some questions which fall into grey areas between sites, and
> I think it's OK to ask and delete, then re-ask if you feel you have
> asked on the wrong site.
>
> But as a general rule, do not cross-post questions, please. Pick a
> site and go with it.
>
> *Jeff Attwood*.

and also

> It is considered outright abuse to copy and paste questions across the
> network.
>
> If you tailor your question to adapt it to the different audiences on
> a site -- and genuinely make an effort to to so -- then it can be
> allowed. But copying and pasting is indefensible.
>
> *Jeff Attwood*

and finally

> There are somewhat rare cases where you may benefit by asking
> different groups of users a similar question, because the context of
> their expertise will provide a different perspective.
>
> But if you are asking the same question of two different groups simply
> to reach a larger audience, I would frown upon that. Ask the question
> first on the site you feel will most likely provide the best answer.
> If you do not receive an adequate answer, then it might be okay to ask
> your question again to another group of users — as long as the
> question is on topic and appropriate for that second site.
>
> But cutting-and-pasting between two sites is never okay. If you want a
> different perspective, you should phrase the question specifically for
> that group.
>
> *Robert Cartaino*

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if someone asks a question in SharePoint exchange which is related to or has tags attached as "C#", "Server 2012" or "windows 8" then question should automatically appear in Stack Overflow, Server Faults or Super User sites respectively.

My suggestion might sound crazy when you read it first time but what I am saying is that, Question should be property of SharePoint exchange but should be displayed in related website's questions list :-).

This will help a user get advise from all aspects and experts.

Cross referencing a question will not going to be any beneficial.

With available features, posting question on both sites is the only right option I can believe.

Comment: Well, that is one suggestion on how to change a fundamental way that the SE sites are structured... but do you have any thoughts on posting the same question to multiple SE sites within the current format?